# How can a unique_ptr be returned by value without std::move?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, copy-elision

```
std::unique_ptr<int> ptr() {
    std::unique_ptr<int> p(new int(3));
    return p;  //  Why doesn't this require explicit move using std::move?
}  // Why didn't the data pointed to by 'p' is not destroyed here though p is not moved?

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<int> a = ptr();  // Why doesn't this require std::move? 
    std::cout << *a; // Prints 3.
}
```

In the above code, the function `ptr()` returns a copy of `p`. When `p` goes out of scope, the data '3' should get deleted. But how does the code work without any access violation?

Comment: It actually uses the `std::unique_ptr<>`'s [move constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr).

Comment: Please see [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316727/returning-unique-ptr-from-functions). And whoever closed this as a dupe of "undefined behavior" needs a coffee.

Comment: This is called [copy elision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization)

Comment: @MattMcNabb There still has to be a viable copy/move copy constructor overload.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is set out in the C++11 standard, **§ 12.8/32**:

> When the criteria for elision of a copy operation are met or would be
>   met save for the fact that the source object is a function parameter,
>   and the object to be copied is designated by an lvalue, **overload
>   resolution to select the constructor for the copy is first performed
>   as if the object were designated by an rvalue**....

(emphasis mine). In plain english, it means that the lvalue `p` can be treated as an `rvalue` when it comes to overload resolution, because it is a candidate for *copy elision*. This in turn means the move constructor is picked up on overload resolution (in actual fact, the move copy is probably elided anyway.)

Answer (score 6):

Because `return` of certain expressions, such as **local automatic variables**, are explicitly defined to return a *moved* object, if the moving operator is available.

So:

```
return p;
```

is more or less similar to:

```
return std::move(p);
```

But note that this will not work for example with a global variable.

```
std::unique_ptr<int> g(new int(3));
std::unique_ptr<int> ptr() {
    return g;  //  error!!!
}
```

Comment: This isn't generally true. It only applies in the situation where `p` qualifies for copy elision.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Which is on every `return` expression with value. And a few other places.

Comment: @rodrigo No, it isn't that simple. The conditions for copy elision are more complicated than that (unfortunately!)

Comment: @rodrigo " in a return statement in a function with a class return type, when the expression is the name of a non-volatile automatic object (other than a function or catch-clause parameter) with the same cv-unqualified type as the function return type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing the automatic object directly into the function’s return value"  .

Comment: @MattMcNabb & juanchopanza: Oh! You both are right! A return of a global variable will not qualify for copy elision, for example.

Comment: @rodrigo Other examples: a function parameter, or something inside an if statement.

Comment: i.e your answer is still wrong.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Fair enough. I've rephrased it. In this answer I prefer to avoid excessive technical terms or too much details.