# Returning local variable of different type is considered as rvalue for overload resolution

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

The following function [compiles](http://ideone.com/B87Ltn)

```
struct Base {};
struct Derived : Base {};
std::unique_ptr<const Base> f() {
  std::unique_ptr<Derived> p(new Derived);
  return p;
}
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25885212/875044), return expression can be considered as rvalue for overload resolution if it is eligible for copy elision. And based on [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), a non-volatile object with automatic storage duration is eligible for copy elision if it is the same type as returning type, which is not the case here.

Do I miss anything? Can anyone point out the sections in standard that allows the above code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rules for this changed between C++11 and C++14.

C++11 12.8/32:

> When the criteria for elision of a copy operation are met or would be met save for the fact that the source object is a function parameter, and the object to be copied is designated by an lvalue, overload resolution to select the constructor for the copy is first performed as if the object were designated by an rvalue.

C++14 12.8/32:

> When the criteria for elision of a copy/move operation are met, but not for an *exception-declaration*, and the object to be copied is designated by an lvalue, or when the *expression* in a `return` statement is a (possibly parenthesized) *id-expression* that names an object with automatic storage duration declared in the body or *parameter-declaration-clause* of the innermost enclosing function or *lambda-expression*, overload resolution to select the constructor for the copy is first performed as if the object were designated by an rvalue.

So your example is ill-formed in C++11, but well-formed in C++14.