# unique_ptr return and copy operator

Tags: c++, c++11, return

Hi I am putting my hands on C++11 and there is a behavior I am not able to understand:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> foo()
{
  std::unique_ptr<int> p(new int(3));
  return p; //1
}
int main()
{
  std::unique_ptr<int> p2 = foo(); //2
}
```

Compile

```
std::unique_ptr<int> p(new int(3));

std::unique_ptr<int> foo()
{
  return p;
}

int main()
{
  std::unique_ptr<int> p2 = foo(); //2
}
```

Don't compile saying that I am trying to use a deleted operation (probably copy), but both //1 and //2 are making copy of the object which is not allowed.

I read the standard:

> When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit the copy/move construction of a class object […] This elision of copy/move operations, called copy elision, is permitted […] in a return statement in a function with a class return type, when the expression is the name of a non-volatile automatic object with the same cv-unqualified type as the function return type […]

But it is not really clear to me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: //1 can't compile, what compiler are you using ? You can `return std::move(p);` when it makes sense to move, and it often is when dealing with unique_ptr

Comment: What isn't clear? `unique_ptr` can't be copied, both `return p` and initialising `p2` with `p` attempt to make a copy.

Comment: Are you surprised by the fact that you *do* or *do not* get an error?

Comment: @quantdev Of course //1 complies, `p` is treated as if it were an rvalue and moved, you don't need `std::move(p);`. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316727/returning-unique-ptr-from-functions). //2 doesn't because `p2` is being copy initialized from `p` which requires an accessible copy constructor. Change it to direct initialization and it'll work `std::unique_ptr<int> p2{p};`

Comment: @Praetorian: Unless the OP is misrepresenting his code, `p` is a global variable. It cannot be automatically moved.

Comment: @Praetorian : OP example is [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1fac182107494589), returning from a global, which is the subtlety here

Comment: so for that to works the variable copy need to be created in the function that returns it ?

Comment: @quantdev Oops, missed that `p` is a global variable. Yeah, it shouldn't compile

Comment: Doesn't compile for me on VS2103 `error C2280: 'std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function`

Comment: yep I made a mistake the first case is compiling, the first case should not be using the global variable. And this is what I don't understand, why in one case it is working and not in the other one.

Comment: You know, most text editors include a nifty "copy" feature, that allows you to store text verbatim in memory provided by your OS. And most web browsers have a corresponding "paste" feature which allows you to retrieve that text.

Comment: @user1594047 I accidentally answered your current question in my first comment by not reading the question as it was posted then closely enough. I once asked the same question a long time ago, and it is answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316727/returning-unique-ptr-from-functions).

Answer (score 3):

As the current questions stands, both lines 1 and 2, should not compile because they are trying to make a copy of a non-copyable type.  It is currently unclear if this is what you are seeing and questioning, or if this is what you are not seeing, and questioning.

If either lines 1 or 2 compile for you, this is a bug in your compiler or std::lib.

**update**

Now there is a new and different question.

And the new question claims that this compiles:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> foo()
{
std::unique_ptr<int> p(new int(3));
return p; //1
}
int main()
{
std::unique_ptr<int> p2 = p; //2
}
```

It does not compile for me.  The first error is:

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'std'
```

If I `#include <memory>`, then the next error is:

```
test.cpp:10:27: error: use of undeclared identifier 'p'
std::unique_ptr<int> p2 = p; //2
                          ^
```

If you are not seeing these errors, your compiler/library is buggy.

**update 2**

Now there is a third question:

This does compile for me:

```
#include <memory>

std::unique_ptr<int> foo()
{
std::unique_ptr<int> p(new int(3));
return p; //1
}
int main()
{
std::unique_ptr<int> p2 = foo(); //2
}
```

(I had to add `#include <memory>` to get it to compile)

But this correctly does not compile:

```
#include <memory>

std::unique_ptr<int> p(new int(3));

std::unique_ptr<int> foo()
{
return p;
}

int main()
{
std::unique_ptr<int> p2 = foo(); //2
}
```

The latter error is on the unmarked line above:

```
return p;
```

This is an error because it attempts to make a copy of `p` which is not a copyable type.

The line marked `//2` is not an error because it is not trying to make a copy of the prvalue returned by `foo()`.  It is instead *move constructing* the value return by `foo()`, and this is using a *moveable type*.

There are many, many references available online about move semantics.  [Here is one](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2027.html), although it is dated.  But it is simple and gets the basics of the ideas across.

Comment: I have modified my question you were right I made a mistake for case1, should not have use the global variable in the first case

Comment: My bad so many errors in my code, I just fix them, I can summarize my question by : what is the difference if the variable returned is declared inside the function or outside.

Comment: So the error is coming from return p ? because visual studio tells me it comes from //2