# Dropping a unique ptr returned from a function?

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

If I have a function `source` that returns a `unique_ptr`, and I have a function `sink` that calls `source` in the following way, it works [clang].

But is the behavior undefined? Or is everything copacetic?

```
class Foo {
  ...
  bool isValid() { return true; }
  ...
}

std::unique_ptr<Foo> source() {
  auto foo = std::make_unique<Foo>();  // let's pretend this is C++14?
  /* ... initialize foo */
  return foo;
}

void sink() {
  if (source()->isValid()) {
    /* do something */
  }
  /* ... */
}
```

Is it valid to use the `unique_ptr` on that line only? And when is the object *theoretically* supposed to be destructed? After that line? At the end of the function?

Comment: are you sure `source` returns `std::unique_ptr<string>` ?

Comment: `return std::move(foo);` is redundant, you could say `return foo;`, apart from that it is valid

Comment: Argh, yeah. I decided partway through that a string maybe didn't make the most sense and forgot to change it.

Comment: Since it's a temporary, it's destroyed after the end of the full-expression, which in your case is the condition of the if statement.

Comment: Do you want to make that the answer? @TheParamagneticCroissant

Comment: @wrhall Thanks, done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of calling a function that returns an object (and not a(n lvalue) reference) is a temporary, therefore it's alive until the end of the full expression, which is the whole condition of the if statement in this case. Hence the code is valid.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, your code is valid. The unnamed temporary `unique_ptr` returned by `source` will be destroyed at the end of the full expression in which it was created, in this case the condition within the `if` statement.

From N3337, *§12.2/3 [class.temporary]*

> ... Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression (1.9) that (lexically) contains the point where they were created. ...

And from *§6.4/1 [stmt.select]*, the grammar for an `if` statement is

> Selection statements choose one of several flows of control.
>
> ```
>   selection-statement:
>       if ( condition ) statement
>       ...
>   condition:
>       expression
>       ...
> ```

---

Note that `return std::move(foo);` is not necessary, you can write `return foo;` and the `unique_ptr` will be [automatically moved](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4316727/241631).