# How to print a value of reference to a pointer

Tags: c++

How can I print a value of a reference to a pointer?

```
int& createInt(){
    auto uPtr = make_unique<int>(2);
    auto ptr(uPtr.get() );
    return *ptr;
}
```

How would I print value `2` when I call `createInt()` function?

```
int& x = createInt();  // what will be the value of "x"
```

Comment: The code you posted is undefined behavior, because you will print the value at a deleted address.

Comment: `std::cout << *ptr << std::endl;` perhaps?

Comment: Or `std::cout << 2 << std::endl;`.

Comment: `int & createInt()`... *what*? I mean, *why*?

Comment: @utnapistim there's no UB in the posted code, but there would be if the calling code used the return value

Comment: @MattMcNabb, I assumed @gath asked about how to print the `2` used in the call to `make_unique<int>`, from the code calling `createInt`.

Comment: But guys, if I call int& x = createInt(); will I not "copy" the reference to a new variable?

Comment: @gath: You'd copy the reference -- a reference to a piece of memory that has been released.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work because a unique_ptr will automatically free it's memory when it goes out of scope.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr

what you can do is

```
int createInt(){
    return 2;
}
```

or

```
int* createIntPtr(){
    return new int(2);
}
```

though that is probably bad practice.  There are other things you can do like passing a reference to a value and editing it, depending on what you want though.

Comment: One can return a valid reference to a local static variable.

Comment: Am I misunderstanding something?  If it's a unique_ptr it's memory should be unprotected when the function ends, meaning even if the data still happens to be the same when accessed later, it's unsafe.

Comment: No your understanding is correct. I just wanted to note this for completeness.

Comment: Thanks; I also found this option while I was nosing around: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316727/returning-unique-ptr-from-functions)