# clang error with std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, clang, c++14, unique-ptr

I have base object called `IList`. Then I have `VectorList`, that inherits `IList`.

then I have function like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<IList> factory(){
    auto vlist = std::make_unique<VectorList>();
    return vlist;
}
```

This compiles without problem under `gcc`, but `clang` gives following error:

```
test_file.cc:26:9: error: no viable conversion from 'unique_ptr<VectorList, default_delete<VectorList>>' to
      'unique_ptr<IList, default_delete<IList>>'
        return vlist;
```

How is proper way to handle this kind of errors?

Comment: Could you provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I assume that `VectorList` is derived from the base class `IList` (judging by the names)?

Comment: @CoryKramer The question explicitly states that. "I have base object called `IList`. Then I have `VectorList`, that inherits `IList`."

Comment: yes, I used java word "inherits", sorry for that

Comment: If your classes are set up as you describe, [they will have no such issue](http://cpp.sh/46y6)

Comment: @CoryKramer Your example code is not 100% identical to this one. There's a difference between returning an rvalue and an lvalue, *especially* for a move-only type.

Comment: @Angew I agree, but you [shouldn't have to explicitly `std::move` during a return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316727/returning-unique-ptr-from-functions)

Comment: Don't forget the virtual destructor for this to work correctly with `unique_ptr`.

Comment: code is identical, classes are present (in includes). code compiles under gcc. there is virtual destructor in IList. Code compiles If I do it the "old" way, e.g. create class with new, add it to uniq_ptr of function return type etc.

Comment: I'd say this is a clang bug since it works when NOT using `auto`, see [this live example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/BES2pVxe8hsN6Awa)

Comment: @Rostislav Isn't it more of an issue of deleting via the base pointer versus an issue specific to usage of `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: @CoryKramer The point here is that the type of `vlist` is *not* the same as the return type. `vlist` is `unique_ptr<VectorList>`, the return type is `unique_ptr<IList>`. So that clause of the standard ("try a move first") does not apply.

Comment: @m.s. But you've given it a *different* type than what `auto` does. Try it again with `std::unique_ptr<VectorList>`.

Comment: @Angew you are right! so clang not applying copy elision seems to be fine in this case and GCC is not complying to the standard then?

Comment: @JamesAdkison `shared_ptr` can handle this without a virtual destructor, so I thought it was worth mentioning.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It appears (your version of) Clang is still following C++11 behaviour in this regard. In C++11, you had to use `std::move` in this case, because the type of `vlist` is different from the return type, and so the clause of "when returning an lvalue, try it as an rvalue first" did not apply.

In C++14, this restriction of "same types required" was lifted, and so in C++14, you shouldn't need the `std::move` in the return statement. But if you need your code to compile with your current toolchain, simply add it there:

```
return std::move(vlist);
```

---

The exact C++11 wording was this:

> **12.8/32** When the criteria for elision of a copy operation are met or would be met save for the fact that the source
>   object is a function parameter, and the object to be copied is designated by an lvalue, overload resolution to
>   select the constructor for the copy is first performed as if the object were designated by an rvalue. ...

The criteria for copy elision (which include "same type") have to be met; they're just slightly extended to cover parameters as well.

In C++14 (N4140), the wording is broader:

> **12.8/32** When the criteria for elision of a copy/move operation are met, but not for an *exception-declaration,* and the
>   object to be copied is designated by an lvalue, **or when the expression in a `return` statement is a (possibly
>   parenthesized) *id-expression* that names an object with automatic storage duration declared in the body or
>   *parameter-declaration-clause* of the innermost enclosing function or *lambda-expression,*** overload resolution
>   to select the constructor for the copy is first performed as if the object were designated by an rvalue.

(Emphasis mine)

As you can see, copy elision criteria are no longer required for the `return` case.

Comment: @Barry I've added a quote from N4140. They didn't change copy elision requirements, but relaxed those on `return` statements.

Comment: then [this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/N5nHpyWXdvRlhMkO) should not compile using `g++ -std=c++11`, right?

Comment: @Barry I believe that the "or" has weaker binding than the "and", i.e. I read it as "When the criteria for copy elision are met.... or when the *expression* in..."

Comment: @Columbo Oh so (Criteria Met And Not Exception And Lvalue) Or (Return Statement Names Object)? This is why we don't write 82-word sentences, boys and girls.

Comment: @m.s. no it does not compile under c++11, also make unique is not present under c++11

Comment: I can confirm that the code is compiled without warning under clang.

Comment: This is a DR against C++11 and so applies retroactively. See [CWG 1579](http://wg21.link/cwg1579).

Comment: @T.C. Can you explain what "applies retroactively" means? Does a C++11 compiler have to implement the C++14 wording to be a conforming C++11 compiler?

Comment: @Angew Well, nobody is selling a "conforming C++11" certification for compilers. It basically means that you can expect to see compilers implement the C++14 behavior even in their C++11 modes.

Comment: @T.C. Makes sense, especially since the C++14 behaviour is strictly superior to the C++11 one. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @Columbo OMG, 7 months later I make the [exact same mistake about this wording](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36752874/1)... SMH... I should write a proposal solely to address the grammar here.

Comment: @Barry I reckon you can get this fixed editorially. See the draft repo.

Comment: @Columbo Threw out an [issue](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/712) with the first wording I thought of. Wonder what'll happen.