# clang, returning std::unique_ptr with type conversion

Tags: c++, clang, c++14

Here is my code:

```
#include <memory>

struct A{};
struct B: A {};

std::unique_ptr<A> test() 
{
    auto p = std::make_unique<B>();

    return p;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    test();

    return 0;
}
```

It doesn't compile on clang with error:

```
main.cpp:11:12: error: no viable conversion from returned value of type 'unique_ptr<B, default_delete<B>>' to function return type 'unique_ptr<A, default_delete<A>>'
```

However, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32742741/clang-error-with-stdunique-ptr) (same situation) it should. 
Did I misunderstand something?

My command line (clang ver 3.7):

```
clang++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
```

Comment: Compiles on gcc 5.3.0 http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73b3835e4eafbc7d . As an aside, your `A` doesn't have a virtual destructor.

Comment: It is the same issue. and gcc accepts it.

Comment: It looks like clang has yet to fix this.  It still does not compile on clang 3.8.0

Comment: @milleniumbug: you are 100% right about destructor, however it was just a fast draft to ilustrate problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a clang bug. From [class.copy]:

> When the criteria for elision of a copy/move operation are met, but not for an *exception-declaration*, and the
>   object to be copied is designated by an lvalue, **or** when the expression in a `return` statement is a (possibly
>   parenthesized) *id-expression* that names an object with automatic storage duration declared in the body or
>   *parameter-declaration-clause* of the innermost enclosing function or *lambda-expression*, overload resolution
>   to select the constructor for the copy is first performed **as if the object were designated by an rvalue**.

The criteria for elision aren't met (because `p` doesn't have the same type as the return type of the function), but the code should still be valid since overload resolution should be done as if `p` were an rvalue.

That said, you do want move elision to happen, so prefer to not use `auto` in this case:

```
std::unique_ptr<A> test() 
{
    std::unique_ptr<A> p = std::unique_ptr<B>();
    return p;
}
```

clang accepts this code *and* move elision will happen. Win win.

Comment: The funny thing is that gcc still has the reverse bug - it allows this code in c++11 mode :D

Comment: @SergeyA: In comment in linked question, there is the explanation: *"This is a DR against C++11 and so applies retroactively. See [CWG 1579](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1579)"*.

Comment: @Jarod42, oh! I didn't know that! Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: What is a "real" DR-to-be-applied-retroactively is not something "official", I believe. Official is only the text of the Standard, by which gcc would not be conforming pedantly. Applying certain DR resolutions to "defective looking" DRs retroactively is generally accepted to not change conformance. But what these certain DRs are isn't written anywhere official, as far as I am aware.

Answer (score 3):

You need to `move` from the unique_ptr. Following code compiles on both CLang and gcc:

```
#include <memory>

struct A{};
struct B: A {};

std::unique_ptr<A> test() 
{
    auto p = std::make_unique<B>();

    return std::move(p);
}
```

Comment: @RafałRawicki, because it is a bug in CLang which still does it in C++11 mode.

Comment: It is a fix for c++11, but code should be valid in c++14.and it is a valid workaround.