# error: declared here unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

This codes compiles successfully.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>
using namespace std;
class A{
        public:
        unique_ptr<A> myval;
        A(){ cout<<"Constrcutor of A is called"<<endl; }
        ~A(){cout<<"Destructor of A is called"<<endl;}
        unique_ptr<A> getsomething()
        {
                unique_ptr<A> myval;
                myval.reset(new A);
                return myval;
        }
};
```

but when I comment local`unique_ptr<A> myval;` compiler throws error.

```
shared_test.cpp: In member function ‘std::unique_ptr<A> A::getsomething()’:
shared_test.cpp:12:10: error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = A; _Dp = std::default_delete<A>]’
   return myval;
          ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/memory:81:0,
                 from shared_test.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:273:7: error: declared here
       unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
       ^
```

I am not able to understand what this error says. What is it?

Comment: Do you understand why the original code does compile? Because that is also an interesting question, and if you don't, the answer to this one could be quite lengthy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your local variable `myval` is hiding the class member `myval`.

> **When the criteria for elision of a copy operation are met** and the object to be copied is designated by an lvalue, overload resolution to select the constructor for the copy is first performed **as if the object were designated by an rvalue**.

In your first case, the returned object is created using `myval` as if it was an `rvalue`, and since it's an `rvalue`, it's allowed to choose the `move` constructor if there's one.

In the second case, a copy must be made so it directly calls the `copy` constructor, which fails since a `unique_ptr` object cannot be copied, and you haven't used `std::move` to make sure the compiler calls the `move` constructor.

Comment: `myval` is always an lvalue, not an xvalue. That there's a special rule saying that in that context you first try overload resolution as if the object were designated by an rvalue doesn't change that fact.

Answer (score 1):

This means that `std::unique_ptr` cannot be copied.

Make your return statement move ownership,

```
return std::move(myval);
```

or return a reference / pointer to the original `std::unique_ptr`, although this won't transfer ownership and is most likely not what you want.

To understand why the original OP code works, see [Returning unique_ptr from functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316727/returning-unique-ptr-from-functions?lq=1)

EDIT: I assume your original body was thus:

```
// ..
unique_ptr<A> getsomething()
        {
                return myval;
        }
```

from what you originally asked.

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks, I've added a link to another question which tackles that issue, if that's what you mean

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: since the return value is a temporary object that will be destroyed as soon as the function exits, thus guaranteeing the uniqueness of the returned pointer- I think this is the answer I am looking for, got from the SO link you gave.