# Return array of wchar_t causing memory leak

Tags: c++, json, memory-leaks, free

I am trying to generate a JSON string from my input arrays . I have used "new" inorder to allocate the memory for this JSON. But I am not sure where to deallocate this memory or if there is a better way to write this function .

```
    wchar_t*  SetExpectedTabsData(_In_ PCWSTR tabUrls[], _In_ PCWSTR tabTitles[], _In_ UINT tabsCount)
{
    wchar_t* tabsDataJSON = new wchar_t[JSONTABDATASIZE], jsonPerTab[256];
    StringCchPrintf(tabsDataJSON, JSONTABDATASIZE, L"\"tabs\":[");
    bool isActiveTab = true;
    for (int i = 1; i <= tabsCount; ++i)
    {
        StringCchPrintf(jsonPerTab, ARRAYSIZE(jsonPerTab), L"{\"id\":%i,\"index\":%i,\"windowId\":1,\"active\":%s,\"status\":\"complete\",\"title\":\"%s\",\"url\":\"%s\"}", i, (i - 1), isActiveTab ? L"true" : L"false", tabTitles[i - 1], tabUrls[i - 1]);
        StringCchCat(tabsDataJSON, JSONTABDATASIZE, jsonPerTab);
        isActiveTab = false;
        if (i != tabsCount)
        {
            StringCchCat(tabsDataJSON, JSONTABDATASIZE, L",");
        }
    }
    StringCchCat(tabsDataJSON, JSONTABDATASIZE, L"],");
    return tabsDataJSON;
}
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Delete it when you are done with it?

Comment: I am not sure how to do that. I need to return the same thing. Is there something like finally where i can do the clean up , after the value is returned

Comment: Why not use a `std::wstring` and don't worry about it?

Comment: Man, I don't know what language this is, but it is not C++... jokes aside, just use std::vector.

Comment: @jetty That is what I was getting at.  Once you are done with the returned pointer then you delete it.  I would follow Joachim Pileborg's advice though and just use a `std::wstring`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    wchar_t*  SetExpectedTabsData(_In_ PCWSTR tabUrls[], _In_ PCWSTR tabTitles[], _In_ UINT tabsCount)
{
    wchar_t* tabsDataJSON = new wchar_t[JSONTABDATASIZE], jsonPerTab[256];
    StringCchPrintf(tabsDataJSON, JSONTABDATASIZE, L"\"tabs\":[");
    bool isActiveTab = true;
    for (int i = 1; i <= tabsCount; ++i)
    {
        StringCchPrintf(jsonPerTab, ARRAYSIZE(jsonPerTab), L"{\"id\":%i,\"index\":%i,\"windowId\":1,\"active\":%s,\"status\":\"complete\",\"title\":\"%s\",\"url\":\"%s\"}", i, (i - 1), isActiveTab ? L"true" : L"false", tabTitles[i - 1], tabUrls[i - 1]);
        StringCchCat(tabsDataJSON, JSONTABDATASIZE, jsonPerTab);
        isActiveTab = false;
        if (i != tabsCount)
        {
            StringCchCat(tabsDataJSON, JSONTABDATASIZE, L",");
        }
    }
    StringCchCat(tabsDataJSON, JSONTABDATASIZE, L"],");
    return tabsDataJSON;
}
```

In main for example:

```
int main()
{
    wchar_t* tabsDataJSON = SetExpectedTabsData(tabUrls, tabTitles, tabsCount);
    //do something with tabsDataJSON
    //..

    //end of scope of tabsDataJSON
    //DONT FORGET TO DELETE IT ON THE RIGHT POINT IF YOU DONT NEED IT ANYMORE
    delete[] tabsDataJSON;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I am calling the SetExpectedTabsData(...)  . How do i access a local variable tabsDataJSON of the function?

Comment: wchar_t* tabsDataJSON = SetExpectedTabsData(tabUrls, tabTitles, tabsCount); is the Point :) @Seb: Thanks... I think I was a bit too lazy...

Answer (score 1):

You are rightly concerned. When you use new then you have taken on the responsibility to call delete at the right time.

The best solution would probably be to use a `std::unique_ptr`. The pointer [can be moved out of the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316727/returning-unique-ptr-from-functions) that created it and it will be deleted and freed automatically according to RAII principles when it goes out of scope.

Create the `std::unique_ptr` in the function:

```
std::unique_ptr<wchar_t[]>  SetExpectedTabsData(_In_ PCWSTR tabUrls[],_In_ PCWSTR tabTitles[],_In_ UINT tabsCount)
{
    //wchar_t* tabsDataJSON = new wchar_t[JSONTABDATASIZE],jsonPerTab[256];
    std::unique_ptr<wchar_t[]> tabsDataJSON{new wchar_t[JSONTABDATASIZE]};
    wchar_t jsonPerTab[256];
    StringCchPrintf(tabsDataJSON.get(),JSONTABDATASIZE,L"\"tabs\":[");
    bool isActiveTab = true;
    for (int i = 1; i <= tabsCount; ++i) {
        StringCchPrintf(jsonPerTab,ARRAYSIZE(jsonPerTab),L"{\"id\":%i,\"index\":%i,\"windowId\":1,\"active\":%s,\"status\":\"complete\",\"title\":\"%s\",\"url\":\"%s\"}",i,(i - 1),isActiveTab ? L"true" : L"false",tabTitles[i - 1],tabUrls[i - 1]);
        StringCchCat(tabsDataJSON.get(),JSONTABDATASIZE,jsonPerTab);
        isActiveTab = false;
        if (i != tabsCount) {
            StringCchCat(tabsDataJSON.get(),JSONTABDATASIZE,L",");
        }
    }
    StringCchCat(tabsDataJSON.get(),JSONTABDATASIZE,L"],");
    return tabsDataJSON;
}
```

Then it gets moved out to your variable in the main program:

```
int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<wchar_t[]> tabsDataJSON = SetExpectedTabsData(tabUrls, tabTitles, tabsCount);
    //do something with tabsDataJSON
    //..

    //no need to remember delete[]
    return 1;
}
```

Also keep in mind that you may want to pass a "plain" version of this pointer to another function at some point. In that case you may call `some_function_that_uses_plain_array_pointer(tabsDataJSON.get());`. Or, if you want to "hand back control" of the pointer to a function that only knows about plain pointers and which will be expected to call delete for you, then you can use `some_function_that_releases_plain_array_pointer(tabsDataJSON.release());`.

Answer (score 0):

```
// call function
wchar_t* mystr = SetExpectedTabsData(...);
// use mystr
// delete it
delete [] mystr;
```

Comment: Will this free memory allocated for tabsDataJSON  ? I have been a java coder for far too long.