# C++ returning MyClass* vs MyClass

Tags: c++, pointers, object, memory-leaks

I have a template class I am creating and I need a method that returns an object of that class and assigns it.  I have a method that takes in 2 objects, creates a new one, and returns it, as well as an overload of the assignment operator to copy members correctly.

I have tried to do this 2 ways (both methods are static).

Method 1:  Works, but isn't this bad practice?

```
template <class T>
MyClass<T>* MyClass<T>::MyFunction(const MyClass& a, const MyClass& b)
{
    MyClass<T> *newObject= new MyClass<T>(a.member, b.member2);

    //...do stuff to the object

    return newObject;
}
```

Method 2: Doesn't work, but isn't this a better line of thought?

```
template <class T>
MyClass<T> MyClass<T>::MyFunction(const MyClass& a, const MyClass& b)
{
    MyClass<T> newObject(a.member, b.member2);

    //...do stuff to the object

    return newObject;
}
```

My fear with method 1 is that I am creating a new object in the heap and not ever destroying it.  I am assigning all of its members to another instance of MyClass, but what happens to the first instance if I perform the operation a second time?  Does the first "new" object I created on the stack just sit there?

The problem I have with method 2 is that the object is going out of scope before my assignment operation overload is called.  I looked into copy constructors and move constructors.  Unfortunately, I do not see those being called in this situation (probably a major lack of experience here).

For completion, here is the remaining portions of relevant code.

```
template <class T>
void MyClass<T>::operator = (const MyClass& b)
{
    if (this == &b) { return; }

    DeleteData();
    //just calls the same member removal operation as the destructor
    //to clear everything out to receive new data

    //...simple member copying stuff
}

template<class T>
inline void MyClass<T>::DeleteData()
{
    //call delete on members which need to be deleted manually
}

template <class T>
MyClass<T>::~MyClass()
{
    DeleteData();
}

template <class T>
MyClass<T>::MyClass(const T member, const T member2)
{
    //member initialization operations
}
```

EXAMPLE USAGE:

```
MyClass<T> myObj1(member1, member 2);

MyClass<T> myObj2(member1, member 2);

MyClass<T> myObj3 = *(MyClass<T>::MyFunction(myObj1, myObj2));
```

TL;DR Question:

When using `new` inside a function to return a `class*` instead of a `class` is the created object destroyed when it no longer has any references?

If not, what is the best practice to return an object that is created in a method?

If so, is this method a bad practice?

I apologize if this has been answered before, I am new enough to C++ that my previous researched has not yielded me a satisfactory answer, likely due to me not knowing what I don't know.

**IMPLEMENTED SOLUTION:**
(I also added a copy constructor.  Without it, this solution still worked for the scope of the question, but there were some items beyond this question's scope that were fixed by one.  Hopefully someone in the future might find this info useful)

```
//this is a static function of MyClass
template <class T>
std::unique_ptr<MyClass<T>> MyClass<T>::MyFunction(const MyClass& a, const MyClass& b)
{
    std::unique_ptr<MyClass<T>> newObj = std::make_unique<MyClass<T>>(a.member, b.member2);

    //...Be the factory...

    return newObj ;
}

int main()
{
    MyClass<T> myObj1(member1, member 2);

    MyClass<T> myObj2(member1, member 2);

    MyClass<T> myObj3 = *(MyClass<T>::MyFunction(myObj1, myObj2));
}
```

Comment: Do you have a copy ctor?

Comment: One option to consider is `std::unique_ptr<MyClass<T>> MyClass<T>::MyFunction(const MyClass& a, const MyClass& b)` to force the sucker to delete when it goes out of scope. That said, you don't have to worry about the return by value version going out of scope before it is assigned. C++ would grind to a halt if that were the case.

Comment: Regarding `void MyClass<T>::operator = (const MyClass& b)` and its implementation, you may find [the Copy and Swap Idiom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) useful.

Comment: @SantiagoVarela no, I did not make a copy ctor because after looking at the default implementation I did not feel it was necessary to make my own version.  Would creating an override of it offer any assistance to this problem specifically?

Comment: @user4581301 that link to the copy and swap idiom is fantastic.  Thank you!

Comment: Having a copy constructor is actually very important. Copy and Swap forces you to have one, but the general rule of thumb, ([The Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)) is that if you need a custom destructor to perform cleanup, then you also need an assignment operator and a copy constructor as well to prevent errors. Copy construction sneaks in when you least expect it. If you observe the Rule of Three ([and Five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)) the best option may be to not use pointers at all.

Comment: I would be perfectly happy to not use pointers, that is why I tried method 2 to begin with.  Unfortunately, my intended implementation apparently does not let the RVO do it's magic, and I don't know how to make that happen manually without pointers :(

I'll have to look into the copy constructor again.  I remember looking through the default one and thinking "that's good enough I guess" then moving on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When using `new` inside a function to return a `class*` instead of a `class` is the created object destroyed when it no longer has any references?

It is not. Anything passed to `new` must be explicitly `deleted`, or passed to a container that assumes ownership of it (e.g. `unique_ptr`).

> If so, is this method a bad practice?

It depends, but typically, yes, returning and dealing with raw pointers in general is discouraged as it is prone to memory leaks. The code you have above indeed leaks (as you described).

> If not, what is the best practice to return an object that is created in a method?

It depends. If you don't mind copying, or if your object has move semantics defined, you can return a concrete object like in method 2 and hope the compiler performs [return value optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization).

If you do mind copying, then consider [returning a smart pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316727/returning-unique-ptr-from-functions) of some sort:

```
template <class T>
std::unique_ptr<MyClass<T>> MyClass<T>::MyFunction(const MyClass& a, const MyClass& b)
{
  auto newObject = std::unique_ptr<MyClass<T> {new MyClass<T>(a.member, b.member2)};
  //...do stuff to the object
  return newObject;
}
```

Comment: Unless you explicitly need "shared" semantics, I'd recommend against using a `shared_ptr` (per The Quantum Physicist's example). C++ forces you to think about data ownership and memory management. `shared_ptr` abstracts that away, but in doing so, can leave you exposed to circular references, or neglecting to think about data ownership properly.

Comment: I'm glad I was at least able to sniff out that leak before full implementation.  Unfortunately, the return value optimization does not perform the right acrobatics for me, likely due to the right-to-left interpretation of operations and overloads (see my edited question for a little more detail on what might cause that).

Comment: Without digging further in why your copy constructor and assignment operators are the way they are, I'd say your best bet is `std::unique_ptr` as described by this answer. Some comments on your question point out to ways to improve your `operator=`.

Comment: You can also try implementing a `MyClass(MyClass&&)` move constructor to help making sure that rvo has the right semantics.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
template <class T>
std::shared_ptr<MyClass<T>> MyClass<T>::MyFunction(const MyClass& a, const MyClass& b)
{
    auto newObject = std::make_shared<MyClass<T>>(MyClass<T>(a.member, b.member2));

    //...do stuff to the object

    return newObject;
}
```

This is the right way to do it in modern C++, if you ever think about returning pointers. The shared pointer will clean everything for you, and you'll not be passing copies. Assuming you don't want to use a move constructor.

EDIT:

Since people criticized `shared_ptr` a lot in the comments, because it's killing a fly with a bazooka (and I agree), I offer also the same with `unique_ptr`. Just be aware that `unique_ptr` is a unique object that must be moved, not copied.

```
template <class T>
std::unique_ptr<MyClass<T>> MyClass<T>::MyFunction(const MyClass& a, const MyClass& b)
{
    auto newObject = std::unique_ptr<MyClass<T>>(new MyClass<T>(a.member, b.member2));

    //...do stuff to the object

    return newObject;
}
```

PS: Notice that I didn't use `make_unique` (as opposed to `make_shared`). This is because `make_unique` is C++14, not C++11.

Comment: Similar to my thinking, but there's no need for the added complexity of `shared_ptr` over `unique_ptr`. With whom is the pointer being shared? No one.

Comment: @user4581301 `unique_ptr` is non-copyable. You can't return it unless you capture it with a move.

Comment: Why not `std::make_shared<MyClass<T>>(a.member, b.member2)`?

Comment: @MárioFeroldi No particular reason... just my style due to trauma when using `shared_ptr` with `std::string`.

Comment: So? It's still not being shared. Move the sucker. That's what move is for.

Comment: @user4581301 I assumed no move constructors are used :) , it's just an assumption ;)

Comment: std::shared_ptr ist still unneccessary, when std::unique_ptr could be used instead.

Comment: If you're using `auto`, might as well also assume that the implementation of `unique_ptr` is movable.

Comment: You can return a `std::unique_ptr` actually, the return statement turns it into an xvalue.

Comment: To be clear, @MárioFeroldi's answer is correct *because* unique_ptr is movable.

Comment: Guys, I'm not against `unique_ptr`. I just think that if we're gonna move stuff, we might as well not use pointers at all and move the whole object! I'm assuming that we won't use move constructors.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist, right, but issue is `shared_ptr` has a big tradeoff tied to it, because its semantics are meant to handle shared resources. Here, you don't have anything similar, so the nitpicking is on your decision to paying for `shared_ptr` without any good reasons.

Comment: @user4581301 Wow... didn't know that :) Thanks!

Comment: @MárioFeroldi Edited the answer. Hope this satisfies everyone now.

Comment: One last nag, prefer `std::make_unique` if available. It eliminates a couple edge cases that can still result in a leak.

Comment: @user4581301 `std::make_unique` is not available in C++11: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique

Comment: @user4581301 That example is complete and extremely helpful!  Glad I dug through the comments (man they grew fast).

Answer (score 0):

It is quite common, in C++ code, to pass pointers around everywhere. Generally speaking, it is best practice to have the creator of a pointer also destroy it. But it is also acceptable to pass ownership of the pointer to someone else have them take responsibility of maintaining and destroying the pointer.

This is especially true in your case where it appears your method is nothing more than a factory method. It is perfectly okay to think of a factory method as being the same as the constructor. And the one who took responsibility for creating - and has responsibility for destroying - the pointer.

If you are less concerned about best practices and just want it to be memory safe, you can use a `std::shared_pointer` in `#include <memory>`. These act kinda like garbage collectors. You use them exactly as you would a normal pointer. But as soon as the last reference to it goes out of scope, it deletes the underlying pointer for you.

Comment: I am concerned with learning both best and memory safe practices.  So many others are recommending either shared or unique pointers, is that not the best practice?  If not, what is?

Comment: Shared pointers do have a slight overhead. But it's negligible enough that shared pointers can, and probably should, be used in most circumstances.Pointer ownership just happens to be a related concept. Basically, you say that only one thing is allowed to manage the pointer so that there's no risk of someone else reassigning or deleting it unexpectedly.

Comment: @MikeyAwbrey Nathan's missing the point of `shared_ptr`. The issue is not about the reference counting and overhead, it is in who owns the pointer and is responsible got management like deletion. Shared pointer implies that there COULD be multiple users of the same pointer. If that isn't the case, use `unique_ptr`. Good write up here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706192/which-kind-of-pointer-do-i-use-when