# What happens when a std::unique_ptr is initialized with a local raw pointer?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

A piece of code snippet:

```
std::unique_ptr<SDL_Renderer, decltype(&SDL_DestroyRenderer)>
cGraphics::Create_Renderer()
{
    SDL_Renderer* temprenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(m_Window.get(), -1, 0);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(temprenderer, 255, 255, 255, 0xff);
    return std::unique_ptr<SDL_Renderer,
                           decltype(&SDL_DestroyRenderer)>(temprenderer,
                                                           SDL_DestroyRenderer);
}
```

What I know:

- `temprenderer` is of course destroyed when it goes out of scope;
- a temporary `std::unique_ptr` is initialized with the raw pointer;
- Although `std::unique_ptr` does not allow copy, it is OK to return by value;
- Essentially the temporary `std::unique_ptr` is also destroyed when it goes out of scope;
- We are now holding a copy of that temporary unique pointer

My question:

Why does the destruction of the raw pointer have no effect on the copy of the temporary unique pointer, which itself (the temporary unique pointer) is initialized with the raw pointer? In other words, what happens inside of that unique pointer that keeps the information from being lost?

My assumption is that the unique pointer also holds a raw pointer (e.g. `.get()`), and when it is initiated by `temprenderer` it copies the value of `temprenderer` onto the raw pointer, and that information is again copied when the unique pointer goes out of scope.

OK now it sounds quite obvious after I thought it through, but I'd appreciate if someone can confirm this. I also found this:

> A unique_ptr explicitly prevents copying of its contained pointer (as would happen with normal assignment)

So maybe something extra happens when we return a `unique_ptr`?

Comment: The destruction of the raw pointer doesn't destruct the thing it points to.

Comment: @tkausl Yes I know that. The only thing that is a bit puzzling is how that piece of information (the address of the object) passes from the raw pointer to the returned unique_ptr. Actually after I wrote everything out it seems to be much clearer. Just need a confirmation though.

Comment: `The only thing that is a bit puzzling is how that piece of information (the address of the object) passes from the raw pointer to the returned unique_ptr.` The same way any other piece of information, for example an int, passes from caller to callee.

Comment: i.e. it transfers ownership

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we return a temporary `unique_ptr`, the compiler actually "moves" the resources by calling move constructor. Once it has moved the resources, the original temporary `unique_ptr` goes out of scope and is destroyed. Even if the `unique_ptr` were a lvalue but if the compiler could figure out that it would anyway go out of scope (not needed anymore) after the function returns, it would perform **copy elision** and select the move constructor for returning.

> Why does the destruction of the raw pointer have no effect on the copy of the temporary unique pointer, which itself (the temporary unique pointer) is initialized with the raw pointer? In other words, what happens inside of that unique pointer that keeps the information from being lost?

Because it's not the content that is being destroyed but the variable which holds the address. And once `unique_ptr` has the address of the content, why does it matter anyway?

> My assumption is that the unique pointer also holds a raw pointer (e.g. .get()), and when it is initiated by temprenderer it copies the value of temprenderer onto the raw pointer, and that information is again copied when the unique pointer goes out of scope.

When a `unique_ptr` is initialized with `temprenderer` it simply copies the address pointed to by `temprenderer` into its own member variable. And that information is **not copied** but **moved(transfer of ownership)** when the control goes out of scope.

You might want to take a look at how [unique_ptr is returned from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316727/returning-unique-ptr-from-functions)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The first part definitely contains more knowledge than I can assume at the moment. I think the only thing I didn't get about your last paragraph is that I have been writing code for a while but never gave it a second thought. I'm going to read more about the move semantics.

Comment: @NicholasHumphrey There you go http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html

Answer (score 1):

> A unique_ptr explicitly prevents copying of its contained pointer (as
>   would happen with normal assignment)

```
template<class U, class E>
unique_ptr(unique_ptr<U, E>&& u) noexcept;
```

`U` is MoveConstructible and MoveAssignable, but is **not** *CopyConstructible* nor *CopyAssignable* as per [unique.ptr/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/unique.ptr#4).

Thus, it prevents copy. Instead it *transfers* ownership.