# How to have "factory function" return a non copyable object?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, copy-elision, noncopyable

#### Context

Trying to create some gzip archive with a different filename inside I wrote this following snippet of code.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/file.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/gzip.hpp>

boost::iostreams::filtering_ostream&& makeGZipStream(const std::string& archiveName,
                                                     const std::string& fileName)
{
    boost::iostreams::filtering_ostream theGzipStream;

    boost::iostreams::gzip_params theGzipParams;

    theGzipParams.file_name = fileName;

    theGzipStream.push(boost::iostreams::gzip_compressor{theGzipParams});

    theGzipStream.push(boost::iostreams::file_sink{archiveName});

    return std::move(theGzipStream);
}

int main()
{
    boost::iostreams::filtering_ostream&& theGzipStream = makeGZipStream("archive.gz", "file");

    theGzipStream << "This is a test..." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

#### Problem

This (as we may expect) produces a core dump because in `makeGZipStream` we try to return a local stack-allocated variable by (rvalue-)reference. But the copy was not an option in this case as `boost::iostreams::filtering_ostream` is non-copyable.

#### Questions

1. We can [return a `std::unique_ptr` "by value"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316727/returning-unique-ptr-from-functions) thanks to its move constructor (and the move should not even occur in C++17 thanks to copy-elision), why isn't it possible in this case ?
2. What are the good solutions there ?

#### Possible solutions

1. Putting everything in the same scope (what I was trying to avoid)
2. Wrapping your object in a `unique_ptr` (not so pretty)
3. Anything else ?

#### Notes

The compiler used was the quite old `g++ (GCC) 4.9.3`.

Comment: Just return and assign `boost::iostreams::filtering_ostream`s. You seem to be making it more complicated than it has to be.

Comment: this is not how you use r-value references.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The type is non-copyable, `g++` complains with I try this option.

Comment: Undefined behavior - returning a reference to a local variable

Comment: @DavidHaim I realized indeed.

Comment: @SergeyA Yes, that's already mentioned in the question.

Comment: @matovitch If you use `return std::move(theGzipStream);` and it still complains, make sure your type has a move constructor.

Comment: @SergeyA Yes, I suspected, but had to try. ;)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux bad practice and not recommended (moving from local variables).

Comment: @matovitch your question is factually incorrect. It works for `unique_ptr`s not because of copy elision, but because of move constructor

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux You're right, the error has to be with the missing move constructor. Unfortunately I am not free to use a more recent version of boost.

Comment: @matovitch Then your type is both non-copyable and non-movable. It can never be returned by value. The easiest workaround is probably to wrap it in a `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @SergeyA Yes, if you use `std::move` like I did, otherwise it's copy ellision. My mistake. :)

Comment: @matovitch, doesn't matter, it still semantically the same. Without move constructor, `unique_ptr` would not be returnable from function (excluding C++ 17 copy elision).

Comment: @matovitch Well, maybe You are not compiling it with C++11 enabled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just return by value and remove `std::move()` from return statement:

```
boost::iostreams::filtering_ostream makeGZipStream(const std::string& archiveName,
                                                     const std::string& fileName)
{
    ...
    return theGzipStream;
}
```

if it fails to compile due to missing move constructor, then you are out of luck and this type is not movable, so wrap it into `std::unique_ptr` and return that pointer by value (which is movable for sure).