# How can a class be made (partial) owner of a pointer given a function that returns a unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

This question is a follow-up to [Why doesn't returning a std::unique_ptr violate unique_ptr's deleted copy constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65114476/why-doesnt-returning-a-stdunique-ptr-violate-unique-ptrs-deleted-copy-constr) (which is answered here: [Returning unique_ptr from functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316727/returning-unique-ptr-from-functions) )

This leads me back to the original problem I'd faced.

I have to work with a function (outside my control) that returns a `std::unique_ptr`. I would like instances of a class to have a reference to the object the `unique_ptr` encapsulates, but I'm unclear and fumbling with the syntax of what's needed to pull this off.

I hope this sample code makes my *intent* clear, given that I can't find the right model/syntax to make this compile: I'd like instances of `class PtrOwner` to be able to "own" some form of reference to the underlying object encapsulated by the `unique_ptr` that is returned by function `getUniquePtr()`:

```
// main.cpp
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

std::unique_ptr<int> getUniquePtr() {
  return std::unique_ptr<int>(new int( 42 ));
}

class PtrOwner {
  std::unique_ptr<int> p_;

public:
  PtrOwner( std::unique_ptr<int> p ) : p_(p) {}
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
  PtrOwner po( getUniquePtr() );

  return 0;
}
```

```
$ g++ --version && g++ -g ./main.cpp && ./a.out
g++ (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

./main.cpp: In constructor ‘PtrOwner::PtrOwner(std::unique_ptr<int>)’:
./main.cpp:13:44: error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = int; _Dp = std::default_delete<int>]’
   PtrOwner( std::unique_ptr<int> p ) : p_(p) {}
                                            ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/memory:81:0,
                 from ./main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/unique_ptr.h:359:7: note: declared here
       unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
       ^~~~~~~~~~
```

What is good practice/accepted convention to pull this off?
I tried fumbling with the concept of `PtrOwner` owning a `shared_ptr` but I'm not adept with that class either, and couldn't pull off the required syntax:

```
// main.cpp
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

std::unique_ptr<int> getUniquePtr() {
  return std::unique_ptr<int>(new int( 42 ));
}

class PtrOwner {
  std::shared_ptr<int> p_;

public:
  PtrOwner( const std::unique_ptr<int>& p ) : p_(p) {}
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
  PtrOwner po( getUniquePtr() );

  return 0;
}
```

(I think the error from the second code block is too spammy for me to reasonably post here)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor in your top example tries to *copy* the `unique_ptr` but a `unique_ptr` isn't copyable.

You need to *move* it instead:

```
#include <utility>

//...

PtrOwner(std::unique_ptr<int>&& p) : p_(std::move(p)) {}
```

There's nothing *partial* about the ownership though. `PtrOwner` is now the owner. Period.

To get a reference to the underlying object, use [`std::unique_ptr::operator*`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator*):

```
int& r = *p_;
```

`r` is here a reference to the underlying  object and can be used to assign new values to the object (e.g. `r = 10;`) but does not own it. The object will continue to exist when `r` goes out of scope and be destroyed when the `PtrOwner` instance goes out of scope (or, if the ownership has been transferred, when the currently owning entity goes out of scope).

Answer (score 1):

> What is good practice/accepted convention to pull this off?

Take @TedLyngmo's suggestion. That is good practice. I'll just offer some additional general intuition:

If your class holds a `std::unique_ptr` rather than a pointer - you can essentially forget about the use of the term "pointer" in there. Think of it as an opaque non-copyable object; you absolutely don't have to worry about any heap storage. It's a bit like, say, an `std::vector`, but without a copy constructor.