# unique_ptr is calling destructor twice

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I have a block of code where I am using `unique_ptr`.

```
class Abc {
public:
    std::string msg;
    Abc(std::string m) {
        msg = m;
        std::cout << "Constructor: " << msg << std::endl;
    }  
    ~Abc() {
        std::cout << "Destructor: " << msg << std::endl;
    }
};


int main() {
    auto p = std::make_unique<Abc>(Abc(__func__));
}
```

But the destructor is called two times. Is there a way I can make it call the destructor only one time?

Comment: you should add a copy constructor with couts, to see all objects that are created in your code

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316727/returning-unique-ptr-from-functions?rq=1) might help

Comment: [OT]: [`std::source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location) (C++20) might replace usage of `__func__`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're constructing a temporary `Abc` (i.e. `Abc(__func__)`) firstly, then pass it to `std::make_unique`, which constructs the underlying `Abc` from the temporary (via the move constructor of `Abc`); i.e. two `Abc` objects are constructed, then destructor are called twice too.

You can pass `__func__` to `std::make_unique` directly, i.e. needn't to construct the temporary `Abc` from the beginning.

```
auto p = std::make_unique<Abc>(__func__); // constructs Abc via Abc::Abc(std::string) directly
```

Answer (score 2):

You create two objects and see both of them destructed. `Abc(__func__)` is a temporary that gets destroyed at the end of the line in main.

Add a user defined move constructor to see how `make_unique` move constructs the object:

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class Abc {
public:
    std::string msg;
    Abc(std::string m) {
        msg = m;
        std::cout << "Constructor: " << msg << std::endl;
    }
    Abc(Abc&& other){
        msg = other.msg + " moved";
        std::cout << "Move Constructor: " << msg << "\n";
    }  
    ~Abc() {
        std::cout << "Destructor: " << msg << std::endl;
    }
};


int main() {
    auto p = std::make_unique<Abc>(Abc(__func__));
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/sz6nfdxq6):

```
Constructor: main
Move Constructor: main moved
Destructor: main
Destructor: main moved
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5P2qL.png are you happy now? :D

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number No no it's absolutely fine. Let's delete off this discussions XD and make SO cleaner

Comment: Thanks. It was to the point explained. :D

Comment: @463035818_is_some property_number: Also you change your mind. how 463035818 can be the largest prime number and not a number depending of the month or your feeling? ;-)

Comment: Suggestion for the next time:  463035818_is_not_a_random_number, to mismatch with explanation *"463035818 is just a random number, nothing more"* ;-)

Comment: @anirudh I was asked about the number so frequently recently that now eventually I wrote it up in my profile. Yes we can clean some comments, next time I can simply refer to my profile

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number hahaha dude you took this to next level ! But definitely your Bio would now help some other curious & troublesome SOers like me !

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I truly appreciate your efforts & intention behind changing your username. I should take some inspiration from you :)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Great People (like you) , make the Great Communities like SO. Thanks sir :)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I respect your anonymity but would definitely like to connect with you on Linkedin.